# React hook / render difficulties

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am using next.js with typescript and a pretty strict eslint config. I am interested in how you would solve this problem.

The use case:
I want to fetch data client side. As soon as the data is there I want to display it. Pretty easy.

Now the problem.

If I put the useEffectHook above the `if(!data)` block I get the "TypeError: filterVaccinationsBy is not a function"

If I use my useEffectHook under the `if(!data)` block I get the "Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render."

How do you solve such things?

Thanks!!

```
    const MyPage: any = (props: { AuthUserInfo: any }) => {
  const [vaccinationList, setVaccinationList] = useState<
    IVaccination[] | undefined
  >(undefined);
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState<
    "noFilter" | "travel" | "children" | "gratis" | "combination"
  >("noFilter");

  const { data, error } = useRequest<Vaccinations>(
    VACCINATIONS_QUERY,
    (query: any) => graphQLClient.request<Vaccinations>(query)
  );

  const changeFilterOrder = (vaccinations: IVaccination[] | undefined) => {
    if (filterOrder === "alphabetical") {
      console.log("in alphabetical filtering");

      const alphabeticalOrder = vaccinations?.sort((a, b) =>
        a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
      );
      return alphabeticalOrder;
    }
    if (filterOrder === "chronological") {
      console.log("in chronological filtering");
      const chronologicalOrder = _.sortBy(vaccinations, [
        function (vacc) {
          return vacc.vacc_start_weeks;
        },
      ]);
      return chronologicalOrder;
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    filterVaccinationsBy("noFilter");
  }, []);

  if (!data) {
    return <p>Loading data...</p>;
  }

  if (error) {
    return <p>Error: {JSON.stringify(error)}</p>;
  }
  const { multivaccination, vaccination } = data;

  const mergedList = vaccination.map(
    ({
      id,
      name,
      description,
      vacc_start_weeks,
      vacc_start_text,
      vaccination_vaccination_plan,
    }) => ({
      id,
      name,
      description,
      vacc_start_weeks,
      vacc_start_text,
      vaccination_vaccination_plan,
      multivaccinationByMultivaccination: multivaccination
        .filter((multivacc) => multivacc.parent_id === id)
        .map(({ vaccinations }) => vaccinations),
    })
  );

  const filterVaccinationsBy = (filterBy: string) => {
    if (filterBy === "travel") {
      setFilter("travel");
      const travelVaccinations = mergedList.filter(
        (vacc: IVaccination) =>
          vacc.vaccination_vaccination_plan[0]?.vaccination_plan &&
          vacc.vaccination_vaccination_plan[0]?.vaccination_plan.target_group?.includes(
            "travel"
          )
      );
      const correctOrder = changeFilterOrder(travelVaccinations);
      setVaccinationList(correctOrder);
    }
    if (filterBy === "gratis") {
      setFilter("gratis");
      const gratisVaccinations = mergedList.filter(
        (vacc: IVaccination) =>
          vacc.vaccination_vaccination_plan[0].vaccination_plan?.dose1_price ===
          0
      );
      const correctOrder = changeFilterOrder(gratisVaccinations);
      setVaccinationList(correctOrder);
    }
    if (filterBy === "children") {
      setFilter("children");
      const childrenVaccinations = mergedList.filter(
        (vacc: IVaccination) =>
          vacc.vaccination_vaccination_plan[0].vaccination_plan &&
          vacc.vaccination_vaccination_plan[0].vaccination_plan.target_group?.includes(
            "children"
          )
      );
      const correctOrder = changeFilterOrder(childrenVaccinations);
      setVaccinationList(correctOrder);
    }
    if (filterBy === "combination") {
      setFilter("combination");
      const combinationVaccinations = mergedList.filter(
        (vacc: IVaccination) =>
          vacc.multivaccinationByMultivaccination.length > 0
      );
      const correctOrder = changeFilterOrder(combinationVaccinations);
      setVaccinationList(correctOrder);
    }
    if (filterBy === "noFilter") {
      setFilter("noFilter");
      const correctOrder = changeFilterOrder(mergedList);
      console.log("1");
      setVaccinationList(correctOrder);
      console.log("2");
    }
  };

  return (<p>Hey beautiful<p> )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your useEffect cannot be under your if(!data) because your functional component would return at that point and never call useEffect. The react doc explain this better than I do, but you can NOT make conditional hooks ! A hook must always been called !

I think your get "TypeError: filterVaccinationsBy is not a function" because filterVaccinationsBy is not defined when called. Put the function declaration above the useEffect, or transform it to non-arrow/standard function.

Comment: I can't put it above the useEffect as I need the data in the function which only get's filled after it is fetched. I am asking for best practices... :)
Also changing the arrow function doesn't help as ESLint is still complaining about that I am using ah function before it's declared...

Comment: First, eslint is not a god, it's a guide for cleaner code, you can always disable the rule for the file/line.

Secondly, if your fonction depends on the data, it's good practise to pass it as an argument of your function instead of using the scope. It is call "pure functions". A pure function could be defined outside of your components.

Comment: sorry. I get a typeError as well afther the fixed eslint error: TypeError: filterVaccinationsBy is not a function. I can't pass in the data, as it's not loaded yet.